# How can I access arrays through switch condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was learning about switch condition and I was wondering if I could access an array through switch condition, I tried to do that but always returns the default state

```js
let color = ['red','blue','green'];

switch(color){
    case '0':
        console.log('the color is red');
        break;
    case '1':
        console.log('the color is blue');
        break;
    case '2':
        console.log('the color is green');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('the color is not red or blue or green');
        break;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing an array"? What's your expected result?

Comment: switch case is for expressing conditions not iterating on an array.
you need to embed the switch case in a for loop, then pass each of the array items to the switch

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for

```js
let color = ['red','blue','green'];

for(var index in color) {
  printColor(index);
}

function printColor(index) {
  switch(index){
    case '0':
      console.log('the color is red');
      break;
    case '1':
      console.log('the color is blue');
      break;
    case '2':
      console.log('the color is green');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('the color is not red or blue or green');
      break;
  }
}
```

Using a `for in` loop, not to be confused with a `for of` loop, you can iterate through the indexes of the array and use the index in the switch statement.

Furthermore, if this is not for practice or exercise, then you should be storing the mapping of the indexing in an object.

```js
let color = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

let map = {
  0: function () {
    console.log('the color is red');
  },
  1: function () {
    console.log('the color is blue');
  },
  2: function () {
    console.log('the color is green');
  }
};

function onDefault() {
  console.log('the color is not red or blue or green');
}

for (var index in color) {
  (map[index] || onDefault)();
}
```

Though in your case you could easily just do

```js
let color = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

const defaultValue = 'not red or blue or green';

for (var index in color) {
  console.log(`the color is ${color[index] || defaultValue}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, there are 2 approaches to convert a color number to color name - either a mapping (Array or Object) or conditions (using `if` or `switch` statements or similar), e.g.:

```js
// using a map from integers to color names
const colors = ['red','blue','green']
let colorNumber = 0
console.log(`Color for number ${colorNumber} is ${colors[colorNumber]}`)

colorNumber = 5
console.log(`Color for number ${colorNumber} is ${colors[colorNumber] || 'unknown'}`)

// using a switch
switch (colorNumber) {
  case 0: {
    console.log('Color for number 0 is red')
    break
  }
  case 1: {
    console.log('Color for number 1 is blue')
    break
  }
  case 2: {
    console.log('Color for number 2 is green')
    break
  }
  default: {
    console.log('Color for other numbers is unknown')
    break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch is used to compare if the value equals particular case or not. In your case you are passing array inside switch but the cases are string. Since array and string do not match you're always getting default result. To fix this you should change color from array to string.

This will run

```
let color = '0'

switch(color){
    case '0':
        console.log('the color is red');
        break;
    case '1':
        console.log('the color is blue');
        break;
    case '2':
        console.log('the color is green');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('the color is not red or blue or green');
        break;
}
```

Your bug is that you're trying to check the equality of array and string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ["red", "blue", "green"];
switch( list.indexOf("red") ){
     case 0:
          console.log("This is red");
          break;
     case 1:
          console.log("This is green");
          break;
     case 2:
          console.log("This is blue");
          break;
}
```

I think this might be what you want.